# Load 100 million rows to DWH daily

Tags: python, database, etl, data-warehouse, greenplum

There are several OLTP Postgres databases which in total accept 100 millions rows daily.
Also there is a Greenplum DWH. How to load this 100 million rows of data, with only little transformation to Greenplum daily?
I am gonna to use Python for that.
I am sure that doing that in the traditional way (`psycopg2 + cursor.execute("INSERT ...`), even with batches, gonna take lot of time and will create a bottleneck in the whole system.

Do you have any suggestions how to optimize the process of data loading? Any links or books which may help also welcome.

Comment: Look at options such as Apache Airflow, Celery, Pandas.

Comment: @dmitryro Airflow is just a task scheduler. Celery more focused in real-time processing, while I need to load data each day overnight at once. Pandas is good for data transformation, but it's kinda slow and will not help with loading. How these solutions may help me?

Comment: If you're concerned with performance and resources more than job taking place as scheduled, look at go, scala, kafka, spark. You can parallelize Pandas or make it concurrent using threading and multi-processing if you need - again Celery, or Tornado framework, if you use Python.

Comment: @dmitryro But kafka is for streaming data, and tornado is a webserver. I could not figure out how that may help with extracting data from OLTP database and loading data into DWH. The main problem here is loading data into DWH, none of this solution are not seeming like they gonna help me. Or I am wrong? Can you please describe how solutions, that have been listed by you, gonna help me with loading data? Thank you in advance

Comment: Also look at https://medium.com/@paulgebhardt/how-to-build-a-lean-data-warehouse-and-business-intelligence-infrastructure-338cb400166b  or https://tuulos.github.io/pydata-2014 or http://www.dataversity.net/

Answer (score 0):

You should try to export data into a flat file (csv, txt etc).

Then you can use some of Greenplum utilities form import data.
Look [here](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/580/best_practices/data_loading.html).

You can do the transformation on data with Python before creating the flat file. Use Python to automate the whole process: export data into file and import data into table.

Comment: With this volume I wouldn’t use the hard disk to avoid more latency. I’d try staying in memory.